# Telerik Kendo UI grid loses custom command event handler after persisting (and restoring) its state

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, kendo-grid

I have isolated the issue, see and try the [full source here](http://dojo.telerik.com/EDUCO/2).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the snippet
2. Click on '**Say Hello**' custom command button, and check if the event
   handler runs
3. Click on top left '**Save State**' button
4. Click on '**Load State**' button, and restore the previous state.
5. Now click again on '**Say Hello**' button and demonstrate the event handle will *not* run, instead something weird is happening.

Notes: Please do not search for the solution around the localStorage. The issue can be reproduced by using different server side state persisting solution. (as my original app does)

Any idea where to patch? ... or workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help you out.

http://dojo.telerik.com/EDUCO/4

I have added the following piece of code for you:

```
dataBound: function (e) {
    $(".k-grid-SayHello").on('click', function (a) {
        console.log(e);
        a.preventDefault();
        alert('Hello');
    });

},
```

When the rebind occurs I suspect that it is losing the connection to the event handler so all I have done if looked for the button based on it's class name and reattached it.

Obviously you can adapt the solution to meet your needs but this is something I do for my projects when I need to "invoke" custom actions on buttons/ dynamically create things on the fly.

Any issues let me know.

Comment: David Shorthose. Thanks I figured out something similar. Please note the dataBound will run multiple times, so you are attaching the event handler also multiple times, and then it will fire unexpectedly multiple times. My solution was use (unconditionally) .off(....).on(....). Horrible solution, it would be great if the grid persistance worked as expected.  Other issues found also, I am spending all my day to battle with persistance

Comment: I guess you could check to see if the elements have been destroyed i.e paged, filtered, sorted etc and then reattach the event if not present. In my scenario's I generally use a client template for any "clickable" actions and the apply the event handler to the templated items afterwards so don't have any issues with potentially adding multiple handlers for the same event. Maybe if you are facing lots of issues try raising a support ticket with Telerik (if you have support) and see if they can suggest a suitable answer.

Answer (score 1):

To keep function references after calling grid.setOptions()
I added the function references back to the deserialized configuration object before passing it to the setOptions method.
( http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-setOptions )

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var grid = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        var originalOptions = grid.getOptions();
        var savedOptions = JSON.parse(localStorage["myGrid-options"]);
        if (savedOptions) {
            var detaylarFunc = originalOptions.columns[3].command[0].click;
            savedOptions.columns[3].command[0].click = detaylarFunc;
            grid.setOptions(savedOptions);
        } else {
            grid.dataSource.read();
        }
    });

    //Custom command
    function Detaylar(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var grid = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        options = grid.getOptions();
        localStorage["myGrid-options"] = kendo.stringify(grid.getOptions());

    }
```